# Modify delete a line using ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to remove only 'fsck.mode=auto' from the following line using ansible.

> foo bar foo.bar=hold fsck.mode=auto foo foo bar foo

The hosts, root user and other privileges are set up else where in the project.

I prefer to use lineinfile if possible over replace. I don't want to delete the whole line but rather only remove whats in the regexp with ''.

```
- name: remove fsck
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/grub2.cfg 
        regexp: 'fsck.mode=auto'
        line: ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- name: Replacing the square brackets and single quotes on new VM IP address in hosts
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Replacing the brackets from the end of the new ip with whitespace
      replace:
        path: /etc/ansible/hosts
        regexp: \'\]
        replace: ''
```

The above works for me to replace "']" with ''

edit: Just noticed you don't want to use 'replace' my bad. I believe you can use 'state=present' to replace using lineinfile

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/lineinfile_module.html Take note of the 'backrefs' option

Answer (score 0):

I think you are interested in backrefs. The code below does what you need. You can also play with white spaces if you want

`- name: Change match only
  lineinfile:
    path: /whatever/file.txt
    regexp: '^(. *)fsck.mode=auto (. *)$'
    line: '\1\2'
    backrefs: yes`

Without those spaces between . and * (formatting piece of s>>t)

Comment: What is the significance of the $ at the end?  in SED it's for the end of the line

Comment: @damaged1988 it's the same here